# Permission error occured after adding custom capability to editor

Tags: php, wordpress

I m new in wp plugins development. I created a single file of my plugin . Now I want to add some custom menus and capabilities only in editors role. It's done but when I click on my custom menu option in editor role. It shows the error.

```
You D'ont HAVE PERMISSIONS to access this page.
```

MY URL:

```
http://mdomain.com/test/wp-admin/admin.php?page=addlisting/addlisting.php
```

This link works good in the admin part. But after login editor part it shows the permission error.
A custom capability added already.

How can I resolve this bug? I'm new in wp plugins development. please help me.'

Here is my code:

```
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'addlisting_activate');
    register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'addlisting_deactivate');
    add_shortcode('addpostform','addlisting_addpostform');
    add_shortcode('listads','addlisting_listads');
    /*Registration Ends*/
add_action( 'admin_init', 'make_editor_menu');        
add_action('admin_menu','addlisting_create_menu');

    /*Admin Menu and Page*/


    function addlisting_create_menu() {
        $role = get_role( 'editor' );
    $role->add_cap('edit_adds_list',true);
    add_menu_page('Ads Listing Settings Page','Ads Listing','edit_adds_list',__FILE__,'addlisting_listads_page',plugins_url('/images/icon.png',__FILE__ ));

}

    function make_editor_menu(){
    $user_info = wp_get_current_user();
    if($user_info->caps['editor']){
    $menu_slug = '';
    $role = get_role( 'editor' );
    $role->add_cap('edit_adds_list',true);
    add_menu_page('Ads Listing Settings Page','Ads Listing','edit_adds_list',__FILE__,'addlisting_listads_page',plugins_url('/images/icon.png',__FILE__ ));
    }}
```

Comment: Please share some code samples on how you utilize the capability and how you're granting the capability for the editor role.

Comment: @ojrask...see the edited post

Comment: Try to remove the `add_menu_page` call (in the `admin_menu` hook) that uses `manage_options` for the capability. If the slug is used twice I presume the last one called will stay in effect (the `manage_options` version in this case, as `admin_menu` will be called after `admin_init`). If you want administrators to be able to access the menu item too, just add the same capability for them too.

Comment: please edit my code....thnks in advance.. because i m new in wp.. i did not geting you properly

Comment: i did it..admin able to access it, but in editor side 2 menus dispayed in menu baar..both are working..now. but i dont know why it shows two menus

Comment: Ah yes, now you can remove the `make_editor_menu` call and it should work fine.

Comment: yes its done.....thank a lot.. ojrask..thnks so much